# MIPS Assembly confusion

Tags: mips

I'm brand new to MIPS and need help with a question.
If

```
.data
alpha: .byte 'g'
```

how do I print the character inside location alpha?
This isn't my actual problem, but it is the concept by which I would apply to my problem

*Not allowed to use command `li`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use service 11 to print a character.

First load the address where the character code to print is located using `la`.

Then load the actual content of that address.

Then you have to load `$v0` with immediate 11 (print character). If you cannot use `li` the you can use `addiu` for example.

Afterwards just call `syscall` to print the character.

Sample code:

```
.data
alpha: .byte 'g'

.text
  la $a0, alpha
  lb $a0, 0($a0)
  addiu $v0, $zero, 11   # effect is the same as li $v0, 11
  syscall
```

Comment: Yeesss thanks, but the project was due yesterday
 I found the answer though :P